# Как правильно отображать ImageField в шаблоне?

Tags: django

Всем привет!

Возможно, тема уже изъезженная. Но что-то до меня не доходит:

Поле в модели:

```
Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/imagination', max_length=100,verbose_name='Ваше изображение')
```

Настройки settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'                     # путь к медиа

MEDIA_URL = 'images/'                     # ссылка к пути к медиа
```

Сами изображения сохраняются в папку рабочего проекта по пути:

> media\static\imagination

Пытаюсь их найти по ссылке

> [http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/static/imagination/название_картинки.jpg](http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/static/imagination/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8.jpg)

Но джанго ничего не подгружает. Если перейти напрямую, то ругается, что не находит в url-ах. Не понимаю, для них отдельно в urls.py надо запись делать?

Прописал в urls:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Тогда по прямой ссылке

> [http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/static/imagination/название_картинки.jpg](http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/static/imagination/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8.jpg)

Картинка уже появляется. Но я не понимаю, как ее правильно отобразить в шаблоне:

Если я пишу `<img src='{{ profile.Image.url }}'/>`, то на выходе получая относительную ссылку: images/static/imagination/название_картинки.png, которая является неверной, поскольку не содержит базового адреса сайта.

Я, конечно, могу передать в контексте какую-либо константу, содержащую базовый адрес сайта и прописывать ее перед `{{ profile.Image.url }}`, но мне кажется это какой-то костыль. Ни на одном сайте не встречал таких рекомендаций. Вопрос, как правильно выводить в шаблон адрес ссылки на изображение согласно django-way или как это делаете вы?

Спасибо

Comment: Режим отладочный или боевой?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, режим отладочный. Я немного поправил вопрос

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, кажется, эта проблема решилась. решилась обычным слэшем перед url: `MEDIA_URL = '/images/'` вместо `MEDIA_URL = 'images/'`

Answer (score -1):

```
{% load static %}
```

Попробуйте в начале html страницы на которой хотите вывести изображение

```
<img src="{% static "название картинки" %}"/>
```

Comment: Вывод производиться так: <img src="{% static "название картинки" %}"/>

Comment: Автор спрашивает про вывод изображений из поля модели, а это media-данные и выводятся они не тегом `static`.

Comment: Ну со static более менее понятно, но авторы джано почему-то рекомендуют разделять static и media ссылки и файлы по разным директориям: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url. _MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL must have different values. See MEDIA_ROOT for more details._

Comment: @digital-mag потому что статичные ресурсы - это то, что раз и навсегда программист добавляет в проект в процессе разработки - стили, js-скрипты, спрайты и тому подобное. А media-данные - это то, что администраторы и пользователи загружают в процессе работы с сайтом.